# How do you apply a formula to each row on a csv panda series?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, formula

I have a csv file of every Latitude and Longitude of a country city:

```
%matplotlib inline
from __future__ import division
# from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import time
import itertools
import urllib
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("USA_BIG_MAP.csv")
df.loc[0:6]
df.dtypes
```

```
ID  LAT LON Location
0   [ANB]   33.58   85.85   Anniston,AL
1   [AUO]   32.67   85.44   Auburn,AL
2   [BHM]   33.57   86.75   Birmingham,AL
3   [CKL]   32.90   87.25   Centreville,AL
4   [DHN]   31.32   85.45   Dothan,AL
5   [OZR]   31.28   85.72   Fort
6   [GAD]   33.97   86.09   Gadsden,AL
```

```
ID           object
LAT         float64
LON         float64
Location     object
dtype: object
```

Im trying to apply a formula using each city Latitude and Longitude inside the variable 'City' which is a complex number and output a list of the complex number to be visualised into a graph

```
Point = complex
City  = Point

def X(point): 
    "The x coordinate of a point."
    return point.real

def Y(point): 
    "The y coordinate of a point."
    return point.imag

formula = City(69 * float( **XX LAT XX** ), -49  * float( **XX LON XX** ))

print(formula)
```

Apologies for my lack of knowledge in python but how can I insert in each row of the city latitude and longitude to the formula? (labelled in XX LAT XX and XX LON XX) and output the list of the complex number?

As an example, here the code only takes in one of the rows, but i want to apply it to all of the rows to make a list.

```
formula_example = City(69 * float(df.loc[1, 'LAT']), -49  * float(df.loc[1, 'LON']))
formula_example
```

```
(2254.23-4186.5599999999995j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply()` to get your goal:

```
df['complex'] = df.apply(lambda x: (69 * float(x.lat), -49  * float(x.lon)), axis=1)
```

###### Example

Creates two new columns, one via apply your formula inline, one via `def convert_coordinates(lat,lon)`:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_coordinates(lat,lon):
    return (69 * lat, -49  * lon)

df = pd.DataFrame([
                    {'lat':33.58, 'lon':85.85, 'location':'A'},
                    {'lat':32.67, 'lon':85.44, 'location':'B'},
                    {'lat':31.28, 'lon':85.72, 'location':'C'}
                  ])
#direct
df['complex'] = df.apply(lambda x: (69 * float(x.lat), -49  * float(x.lon)), axis=1)

#via def convert_coordinates
df['complexDef'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_coordinates(float(x.lat), float(x.lon)), axis=1)

df
```

###### Output

|  | lat | lon | location | complex | complexDef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 33.58 | 85.85 | A | (2317.02, -4206.65) | (2317.02, -4206.65) |
| 1 | 32.67 | 85.44 | B | (2254.23, -4186.5599999999995) | (2254.23, -4186.5599999999995) |
| 2 | 31.28 | 85.72 | C | (2158.32, -4200.28) | (2158.32, -4200.28) |